# Custom MVC Extension Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I create in mvc methods that have other methods as below?

```
@Html.TextBox(m => m.Password).Class("test").Placeholder("Password");
```

Comment: You cannot do it precisely like that. @Html.TextBox returns MvcHtmlString, so for this syntax to work you would need to make your methods Class and Placeholder extension methods of MvcHtmlString. Which is tricky and inefficient because they'd have to parse Html.

Comment: Could it have something assim@Html.ClassTest (). TextBox (x => x.password.) Class (""). Placeholder ()?

Comment: The telerik controls eg work this way

Comment: Class would need to be an extension method for MvcHtmlString and so would Placeholder.

Comment: If you have extension method for MvcHtmlString that has to modify that string, you'd have to parse it. Which seems to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the approach of [HtmlTags](https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/htmltags). Specifically, implement custom HTML helper methods that don't return MvcHtmlString, but an object that implements IHtmlString and provides an API for chaining methods and building an object model behind the scenes. Razor will call ToString() on the object when it is time to render and will not encode the string thanks to the IHtmlString marker interface.